# What is an efficient way to replace specific words (but not words that include the string in criteria)?

Tags: python, string, text, replace

I am creating a list with pairs of words in a large text. I am going to use those pairs for other tasks later on.

Let's say these are the words I am looking for:

```
word_list = ["and", "car", "melon"]
```

And I'm trying to find all instances of these exact words and change them into "banana".

*Method 1:*

```
for word in range(len(text.split())):
    if word in word_list:
        word = "banana"
```

*Method 2:*

```
for word in range(len(text.split())):
    word = word.replace("and", "banana")
    word = word.replace("car", "banana")
    word = word.replace("melon", "banana")
```

I feel like both of these options are far from efficient. What are some better ways to deal with the problem?

Things to note:

- The end result will be a list of lists: `[["He","has"],["has","a"],["a","banana"]]`
- Only exact matches should be replaced (*watermelon* should not become *waterbanana*)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to do that,

```
value = 'banana'
d = {'and': value, 'car': value, 'melon': value}
result = ' '.join(d.get(i, i) for i in text.split())
```

You can create the mapping dictionary like this,

```
value = 'banana'
word_list = ["and", "car", "melon"]
d = dict(zip(word_list,[value]*len(word_list)))
```